# How to determine if an integer belongs in a range of integers?

Tags: c, operators, range

I want to compare a value against the two ends of the range. This is how my code looks like:

```
if ( timeramount >5 && <10 )...do some stuff...
```

So my application needs to know if `timeramount` is greater than 5 but less than 10.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `if ( timeramount >5 && timeramount <10 )` I suggest you to read the (very) basics before posting questions like this.

Comment: "tried Google, found a few sites on maths but not on something like this" - you're kidding, right?

Comment: thanks for your comments , i am used to working in BASIC , well 20 years ago so i know what i need to do , but the OS is very different..give ppl a break , im sure when you started you asked the 'basic' questions..its learning a new skill...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logical operators such as `&&`, `||` etc. take two operands. Those operands must be expressions. `< 10` is not a valid expression, as it is missing one operand ("what is less than 10?").

To express in C what in natural language you described as "if timerarount is greater than 5 but less than 10", you must be more verbose:

```
if (timeramount > 5 && timeramount < 10) {
    /* if timeramount is greater than 5 AND timeramount is less than 10 */
    ;
}
```

I suggest you grab a good introductory book on C in order to learn the basics of the language. Kernighan & Ritchie's "The C Programming Language" is a good start but you can consult [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: `if timeramount is greater than 5 and less than 10` would actually be valid code in Cobol. :-)  But not in C.

Comment: awesome , yep i was still thinking that you needed to put parenthesis around the values...thanks